# Not all the content of my latex file gets included when the pdf is compiled

Tags: graphics, floats

I am using the float package to insert images into my latex file and for some reason the last image and whatever text is written after it does notm appear in the output pdf file. I have for now solved it by just including another image that will not show up at the end but this is not a real solution. I have no idea what is causing this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: latex does not drop text with no warning, show a small example document with teh problem, or at least show your error messages from the log, or you have `\end{document}` mid-file, everything after that is ignored

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have only one \end{document in the file} if that was the issue I would not be posting the question. The error log is [here](https://imgur.com/a/UsKe0UD) and the file in question is [here](https://unilj-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jk6330_student_uni-lj_si/EYrB6CcJUX5LoeEv_P2r6kkBll35a-YOY8uHyzjWSo-q0g?e=LNcev6)

Comment: that's not the log file it's just an image of part of an editor summary of the errors which is not much use for debugging

Comment: don't use external documents make a small file that you can add to a code block in your question you can use `example-image` so it doesn't need any external image files.

Comment: Your terminal and log end with `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 84 (\begingroup)
### bottom level`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log ends with

```
\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 84 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
```

meaning you start more groups than you end,

Normally in latex, that would be `\begin{aaa}` with no matching  `\end{aaa}` but you have on line 84

`\begingroup`

with no matching `\endgroup` so delete that.

But the real error is

```
\let\clearpage\relax
```

This completely breaks latex and makes it highly likely that you lose text

so delete that line as well, and the document works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does indeed fix the issue.